# The transaction was not sent to the host because of a duplicate order id

Tags: php, payment-gateway

Moneris payment gateway issues my form code is like this

```
<FORM METHOD="POST" ACTION="https://www3.moneris.com/HPPDP/index.php">
 <INPUT TYPE="HIDDEN" NAME="ps_store_id" VALUE="xxxxxxxx">
<INPUT TYPE="HIDDEN" NAME="hpp_key" VALUE="xxxxxxx">
<INPUT TYPE="HIDDEN" NAME="charge_total" VALUE="1.00">
<INPUT TYPE="SUBMIT" NAME="SUBMIT" VALUE="Click to proceed to Secure Page">
</form>
```

This code was running properly for the past few months. But now I've suddenly started getting an error message:

```
The transaction was not sent to the host because of a duplicate order id
```

This is on all my transactions. Could you please help me to fix it? Thanks in advance/

Comment: Have you looked up the error message? Have you checked out the documentation for Moneris?

Comment: yes i checked and requested with moneris customer care. They could not solve the issues. They directing me to test mode. And could find any such issues in documentation

Comment: Possibly a silly question - but which of those fields is the order ID? Are you sure that you're setting a unique value for it? Does the order ID have to be unqiue for your store, or globally?

Comment: It naturally orderID  generated by moneris website itself. we dont need to create a orderID and please check response data below Array ( [mode] => failed [response_order_id] => Cup150513 null  null  null [charge_total] => 34.95 [response_code] => null l [message] => The transaction was not sent to the host because of a duplicate order id [trans_name] => purchase [cardholder] => [f4l4] => [card] => [expiry_date] => [result] => 0 [avs_response_code] => [cvd_response_code] =>  )

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There must be an order ID in your code somewhere else. I tested the above code in both Moneris production and in Moneris QA and it worked without any errors.

If you don't specify an Order ID in your code then moneris will automatically generate a unique order ID for you.

In your response variables (that you recieved back from Moneris) you have this variable response listed:

```
 [response_order_id] => Cup150513
```

However  *Cup150513* is not a Moneris Hosted Pay Page generated order ID. A Moneris Hosted Pay Page order ID will always start with mhp for example:  *mhp123456789*. Since there's no order ID specified in the above code snippet - and since the above code works - it means that the order ID must be somewhere else in your code.

Here's what you can do:

1. Look for the keywords order_id and Cup in your code to find out where the order ID is being generated.
2. Remove the code that generates the order ID or change the code so that the order ID is always unique

Answer (score 0):

I had the same error (using xml server posting), whenever the data I was sending it ended the same way:

```
{ result: 'success',
  code: 200,
  data:{
     ReceiptId: null,
     ReferenceNum: null,
     ResponseCode: null,
     ISO: null,
     AuthCode: null,
     TransTime: null,
     TransDate: null,
     TransType: null,
     Complete: false,
     Message: 'The transaction was not sent to the host because of a duplicate order id',
     TransAmount: null,
     CardType: null,
     TransID: null,
     TimedOut: false,
     BankTotals: null,
     Ticket: null,
     IsVisaDebit: false
    }
}
```

The solution?
I removed the field "wallet_indicator" and now I get a complete answer!